# how to add a link that its "href" is editable in word press panel?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to create a link in theme file that its href value is editable in wp panel?
e.g.

```
<a href="<?php wp_editable_link(); ?>">view some page</a>
// wp_editable_link() is that function I need to find...
```

So ... any ideas?

Comment: Store it as an option …? https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting a question. If you still have specific issues, you can post a specific question with details of the error and what you have tried so far. including your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.
thanks to @CBore

---

I should use `update_option()` for saving/updating the value.

and use `get_option()` to get my value.

and also create a panel for my wp theme that those values are editable there.

- [`update_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/)
- [`get_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/)
- [create options panel](https://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-theme-options/)